# I want to print number mirror pattern in java. with user input

Tags: java

I am trying to print number mirror pattern with user input in java.
here when user give input up to 10 it  printing pattern perfectly.

[image: img1]

but when user give input more then 10 it not printing pattern perfectly ex(11)

[image: img2]

I think there my be issue with spacing.
here below I am also providing code.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TriangleMirrorPattern {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number of rows: ");
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        printTriangleAndMirror(n);
    }

    public static void printTriangleAndMirror(int n) {
       
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print(j);
            }
            for (int j = n; j >i; j--) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int j = n; j >i; j--) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int j = i; j >=1; j--) {
                if(j==n){
                    continue;
                }
                System.out.print(j);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to make my code dynamic so that any number of input can print pattern perfectly

Comment: Your code is only catering for single digit numbers, although stopping at 10 works because of an extra space. You need to check the value of `j` when you print the space, and print more than one for numberst greater than 9.

Comment: How would the output have to look for 11 and for 12?

Comment: You can see in output for 10 it is perfect. The problem when user give input number greater then 10 then output patten is not perfectly printing use can see in above images link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code actually only prints a consistent output for 10. For 9 (and less), we get this kind of effect:

```
1                1
12              21
123            321
1234          4321
12345        54321
123456      654321
1234567    7654321
12345678  87654321
12345678987654321
```

So let's first look at this problem: This is because your space-printing loops both deal with `j` equal to `n`. This "bug" happens to be what you need for the case where `n` is 10, but only for that case. This is because "10" needs two positions, and so that double print of the `n`<sup>th</sup> space happens to come out right.

But this can be solved more generally by determining the number of spaces dynamically: check how many positions are needed to print `j` (in decimal notation) and print as many spaces.

Here is the correction of the space-printing loops:

```
            for (int j = n; j > i; j--) {
                // Print a number of spaces that corresponds to 
                //    the number of digits that j has:
                System.out.print(" ".repeat((j+"").length()));
            }
            // Don't let j be equal to n again:
            for (int j = n - 1; j > i; j--) {
                System.out.print(" ".repeat((j+"").length()));
            }
```

This now fixes the issue for any positive `int` value as input.